# Write strings in array to plist

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, plist

I have a plist with an array and some strings in the array. So I am wondering how to write a new string to the array in the plist. When I use the code below to get the strings from the plist I just get null in the log.

```
NSMutableArray *myPrimaryinfo = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"/private/var/mobile/Library/Keyboard/UserDictionaryWordKeyPairs.plist"];

NSLog(@"%@", myPrimaryinfo);
```

My plist looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <string>Test string1</string>
    <string>Test string2</string>
    <string>Test string3</string>
    <string>Test string4</string>
</array>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 2):

get your path of the file like below and try..

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"DrinkArray" ofType:@"plist"];
```

Comment: The actual path to the plist is: /private/var/mobile/Library/Keyboard/UserDictionaryWordKeyPairs.plist

Comment: primaryList.plist was just a copy of if

Comment: actually you need to just include plist in the project and whenever you will compile the project plist will be included in the simulator path...

Comment: How do I include a plist that isn´t inside my projects document directory or application bundle?

Comment: simply right click on your project and click `Add Existing files` and select the plist from your path and that is done.. the plist will be included in your project

Comment: I think there is a missunderstanding here. The plist that the application is using can be changed either by the application istself or by settings application. So if i store the plist in my application bundle the plist can´t be changed by the rest of the system and so on. So i have to write the data directly to the plist at the following path: /private/var/mobile/Library/Keyboard/UserDictionaryWordKeyPairs.plist

Comment: which path is this??? is that path is of iPhone or local system?? if the path is of iPhone then try to add that path in the code..

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that on iOS, because the file system is opaque outside of your app's sandbox. For more info on what's available to your app in the iOS filesystem, read this:

http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/RuntimeEnvironment/RuntimeEnvironment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH2-SW12

Instead of trying to access portions of the filesystem that are unavailable to your app, consider including the plist file in your app's bundle. If you want the app to be able to dynamically modify the plist, you can save a copy of it to the Documents directory parallel to the app bundle, and from then on read the plist from there instead.

Comment: Okey, lets say that the plist is included in my application bundle, then how can I add new strings to a array in a plist? :)

Comment: That's an entirely different question, and one that's been answered many times on SO, for example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2292347/creating-a-plist-file-programatically

Comment: A great place to start though, is Apple's documentation: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/CreatePropListProgram/CreatePropListProgram.html